# DocuSign For Salesforce All Contact Roles

Tags: docusignapi

When defining a custom opportunity button, what parameters can be used that would load the full set of contact roles associated with the opportunity as envelope recipients when creating an envelope?

Example. If an opportunity had 10 contact roles, then all 10 (contacts) contact roles would list as recipients. If it had 5 contact roles, then all 5 would load as recipients, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a call to CRL to include all contacts in the opportunity: `LoadDefaultContacts`. It might look something like this:

```
CRL=’LoadDefaultContacts~1’;
```

The problem is although all Contacts in the Opportunity will be pulled into the envelope, there is no guarantee that the contacts will fall in the signing order you might expect. You may need to add CCRM and CCTM to sort the order of the contacts.

Comment: Adding the CRL parameter did the trick. The entire contact role list is included in the recipient list. Is it possible to validate the recipient list upon sending? Example: If signer roles 'customer' and 'legal' are not included in the recipient list then throw an error and prevent the send from occurring.

Comment: Thanks can you accept my answer if it worked?  Regarding your followup question, I think the answer is yes but you'd have to write the logic yourself.  You can make an API call to check and see what templateRoles are available on the template, then parse the text to see what roles have been entered and throw an error if needed